# can logo.png in my header ignore my custom css stylesheet? (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphical-logo

I just want the png to overlap my already built (bootstrap) header, so basically ignore it.

could I modify app/views/home/index.html.erb so that the png just sits independently of what the css does?

Comment: can u explain in bit more detail.  I personally didn't get your question :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to position the png where you want it.   In your custom stylesheet, try something like:

```
img#id-of-image {
  position: absolute:
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

You can play with the top and left values to position it where you want.

If you need to nest it inside something, you need to put it within a container (ie. a div) and set the position of that container to "position: relative;".  Then the top/left will be relative to the inside top corner of the container.